# Convert 2 char into 1 int

Tags: c, casting, char, int

I have 2 chars: HIGH and LOW and I'd like to convert them to an int corresponding to HIGH + the 2 left bits from LOW.

I tried somethine like :

```
unsigned char high;
unsigned char low;
high = 128; // 10000000
low= 128; // 10000000
int result; (should be high 10000000 + 2 left bites of low 10 = 1000000010)
// To do
return result;
```

Edited for more clarity.

The solution I chosed is:

```
return high*4 + (low >> (CHAR_BIT - 2));
```

Comment: `char *HIGH;
char *LOW;` remove the asterixs.

Comment: And result = (HIGH << 8) + LOW; Doesn't work for you?

Comment: Did you know that C has [bitwise operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C)?

Comment: @ATaylor, that's not the operation the OP is trying to do, but I'd guess you're on the right track.

Comment: @CarlNorum Yeah, I know, that's why it's a comment, not an answer. But that's what I like to do, when I want to convert two chars into an integer.

Comment: result = high; result *= 256; result + low;  careful not to shift on a char or you'll just overflow it.

Comment: Too many conflicts in the question itself to answer.  Should the low value really go in the LEFT (as in most significant) two bits?  Of an integer of what width?  Should all of the bits from high be retained, or only those which do not have replacements from low?

Comment: Over and above the other issues, you need to initialize `result` to `0` beforeyou start adding to it.  Otherwise you're adding to garbage; GIGO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare `HIGH` and `LOW` as `char*`, but you don't use them as pointer. The following code works fine (BTW, avoid upper case identifiers when you don't use constants):

```
char high = 125;
char low = 12;
```

This is how I understand your question (it could be more understandable):

```
#include <limits.h>

int result = high + (low >> (CHAR_BIT - 2));
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, if high = 100 and low = 128 then result = 100 + 2. Am I right?

Comment: @Leo: Yes, you are. (BTW `char` could be signed and could be unable to hold the value `128`. Use rather `unsigned char` to do that.)

Answer (score 1):

> I have 2 chars, HIGH and LOW, and I'd like to convert them to an `int` corresponding to HIGH + the 2 left bits from LOW.

Your specification is not clear.  Given:

```
unsigned char HIGH = 152;
unsigned char LOW  =  12;
```

It could mean:

```
int result = HIGH + (LOW >> 6);   // Assuming CHAR_BIT == 8
```

Or it could mean:

```
int result = HIGH + (LOW & 0xC0);
```

Or it could mean:

```
int result = (HIGH << 2) | (LOW >> 6);
```

Or it could have some other meaning.  For the values shown in the question, the first two expressions produce the same answer.

To get a more meaningful answer, you'll have to spell out the requirements much more carefully.  Your actual code bears almost no discernible relationship to the requirement you specify.  You have two `char *` variables; you initialize them to what are almost certainly invalid addresses; you don't initialize `result`.  Your computations are, at best, odd.