# converting unsigned char > 255 to int

Tags: c++, char, unsigned-char

I'm programming with a [PLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_controller) and I'm reading values out of it.

It gives me the data in `unsigned char`. That's fine, but the values in my PLC can be over 255. And since unsigned chars can't give a value over 255 I get the wrong information.

The structure I get from the library:

```
struct PlcVarValue
{
    unsigned long   ulTimeStamp         ALIGNATTRIB;
    unsigned char   bQuality            ALIGNATTRIB;
    unsigned char   byData[1]           ALIGNATTRIB;
};
```

- `ulTimeStamp` gives the time
- `bQuality` gives true/false (be able to read it or not)
- `byData[1]` gives the data.

Anyways I'm trying this now: (where `ppValues` is an object of `PlcVarValue`)

```
    unsigned char* variableValue =  ppValues[0]->byData;            
    int iVariableValue = *variableValue;
```

This works fine... untill `ppValues[0]->byData` is > 255;

When I try the following when the number is for example 257:

```
unsigned char testValue = ppValues[0]->byData[0];
unsigned char testValue2 = ppValues[0]->byData[1];
```

the output is `testvalue = 1` and `testvalue2 = 1`

that doesn't make sense to me.

So my question is, how can I get this solved so it gives me the correct number?

Comment: The array is not long enough for a start - the index 1 does not exist in that structure

Comment: I think `byData` is most likely a variable length array.

Comment: [Why use array size 1 instead of pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390331/why-use-array-size-1-instead-of-pointer), but you probably need to read the documentation for the structure to understand how to get data out of it.

Comment: byData is an unsigned char? it says so in the struct. I can even change it to `unsigned int` but then the values below 255 will give me wrong information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert 2 char into 1 int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894209/convert-2-char-into-1-int)

Comment: @crashmstr this is the documentation is giving me about this struct: unsigned char byData[1]; Array with the value. The size of this array depends on the data type (byData[1] is only a placeholder with the minimum size). Should only be accessed, if bQuality is TRUE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That actually looks like a variable-sized structure, where having an array of size `1` at the end being a common way to have it. See e.g. [this tutorial about it](http://www.drdobbs.com/questions-answers-creating-variable-siz/184403480).

In this case, both bytes being `1` for the value `257` is the correct values. Think of the two bytes as a 16-bit value, and combine the bits. One byte will become the hight byte, where `1` corresponds to `256`, and then add the low bytes which is `1` and you have `256 + 1` which of course is equal to `257`. Simple binary arithmetic.

*Which* byte is the high, and which is the low we can't say, but it's easy to check if you can force a message that contains the value `258` instead, as then one byte will still be `1` but the other will be `2`.

How to combine it into a single unsigned 16-bit value is also easy if you know the bitwise shift and or operators:

```
uint8_t high_byte = ...
uint8_t low_byte = ...
uint16_t word = high_byte << 8 | low_byte;
```

Comment: ye I tried it, it says testValue = 2 testValue2 = 1. ok got that. It worked for me :) thank you very much!

Comment: Is this also possible for a uint32_t? for 3 chars?

Comment: @Bart Of course, but then you need four bytes, not only three. :)

Comment: Oh right, since 16 needs 2, 32 needs 4. Sound decent :). how can u convert 4 to 1 uint32_t?

Comment: @Bart Yes that's right. But be careful to make sure the message structure *have* four (or two) bytes, or else you will go out of bounds.

Comment: well the documentation says the `byData[1]`, is just the minimum, so when I get a huge number it will just expand to `byData[4]`