# Get sample in tremor

Tags: c, vorbis, oggvorbis

I have to use tremor to decode ogg vorbis in my project due to much simplier integration (to use on ESP-32). Its [docks](https://svn.xiph.org/trunk/Tremor/doc/ov_read.html) says:

> It returns up to the specified number of bytes of decoded audio in host-endian, **signed 16 bit PCM** format. If the audio is multichannel, the channels are interleaved in the output buffer.
>
> …
>
> Signature: long ov_read(OggVorbis_File *vf, **char *buffer**, int length, int *bitstream);

Now I'm confused about how to read 16-bit signed samples from char array. Do I have to follow some advices from here [Convert 2 char into 1 int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894209/convert-2-char-into-1-int) or do some other thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the buffer two elements at a time. Since the data is in little-endian form ( according to documentation ) you can directly represent two characters as a signed 16 bit integer, in this case 'short'

```
long numBytesRead = ov_read(vf, buffer, length, bitstream); //length is typically 4096

if( numBytesRead > 0 )
{
    for(int i=0; (i+1)<numBytesRead; i=i+2)
    {
        unsigned char high = (unsigned char)buffer[i];
        unsigned char low = (unsigned char)buffer[i + 1];

        int16_t var = (int16_t)( (low << 8) | high );
        //here var is signed 16 bit integer.
    }
}
```

Comment: `i<numBytesRead && (i+1)<numBytesRead` I think you can drop left part.

Comment: Also, will `low << 8` casue overflow?

Comment: Removed the left part of the condition. About overflow, no it wont cause overflow, since we are catching the result in bigger data type. You can try this:   int16_t c1 = (int16_t)((0xff << 8) | 0xbb); and observer the memory of at the &c1 to check for yourself.

Comment: A "signed 16 bit integer"? There is a type for that, and that is `int16_t`.